# Find a record which doesn't exist (foreign key doesn't correspond to pkey in secondary table)

Tags: mysql

Table `albums`:

| id | title | artist_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hits1 | 2 |
| 2 | hits2 | 4 |

Table `artists`:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | michael |
| 2 | katy |

`albums`' record with id = 2 doesn't have a corresponding artist (no record in `artists` table with id = 4).

I want the albums that even having an `artists_id` don't have a corresponding record in the `artists` table (the record in `artists` with that `id` doesn't exist).

This is the output I want:

| id | title | artist_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | hits2 | 4 |

#### Important

I need it for MySQL

Comment: If you really had a foreign key, then this couldn't happen to begin with

Comment: Is that true? What about if someone deleted the record manually directly in the database? Would MySQL avoid deleting that record?

Comment: In theory the database should prevent that (and it's the whole point of a foreign key constraint), but MySQL is known to sometimes silently ignore foreign keys without letting the user know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from albums where artist_id not in (select id from artists)
```